# insert character in particular position in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have a pipeline delimited file and I want to add a new word after field/ column 24 (indicated as filename in to be sample), i tried using

```
awk -F "|" '{{$(NF-2)="filename.txt"} print $0 }' OFS="|"
```

But this overwrites the adjacent columns.

as in:

```
0|ZZZZZ|Mr XXXXX|73 Up hill|Hurley|Atherstone|||XXX XXX|GB|00.01.2017|2134567686|7902379xxx|01.09.2017|25|||239|Stores Sheffield|||07.01.2018|13.10.2016||X||NP
```

to be:

```
0|ZZZZZ|Mr XXXXX|73 Up hill|Hurley|Atherstone|||XXX XXX|GB|00.01.2017|2134567686|7902379xxx|01.09.2017|25|||239|Stores Sheffield|||07.01.2018|13.10.2016||filename|X||NP
```

with awk:

```
0|ZZZZZ|Mr XXXXX|73 Up hill|Hurley|Atherstone|||XXX XXX|GB|00.01.2017|2134567686|7902379xxx|01.09.2017|25|||239|Stores Sheffield|||07.01.2018|13.10.2016||filename|||NP
```

can some help me with adding a word at particular position without overwriting.

Comment: why only the last line has changed?

Comment: do you want to set value of that column (NF-3), or add a column with that value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - didn get you!!

Comment: @guido -  i wanna add a new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed with support for ERE ( `-E` or `-r` depending on your sed version):

```
sed -E 's/(([^|]*\|){24})/\1filename.txt|/'
```

Comment: im getting -E is invalid

Comment: -r works, thanks Sundeep and getting correct output now.

Comment: @NaP yeah that depends on your version of sed, -E is POSIX but still not portable everywhere, while for instance -r is not available on osx

Comment: @NaP see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers when your question is answered

Answer (score 0):

What about this, the idea is like thinking the files is a `csv` but using `|` as a delimiter:

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN { OFS = "|" } {$24="filename"}1' file
```

But this outputs:

```
...13.10.2016|filename|X||NP
```

Not with an extra `|` like in your desired output example:

```
...13.10.2016||filename|X||NP
```

Could it be a typo?

In any case answer from @akshay-hegde is short and clean:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$24=FILENAME}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a pipeline delimited file and I want to add a new word after character position 24 (indicated as filename in to be sample),

At char position 24, its will not give expected output, probably what you need is as follows, which will set 24th column in record with filename.txt,

```
0|ZZZZZ|Mr XXXXX|73 Up hill|Hurley|Atherstone|||XXX XXX|GB|00.01.2017|2134567686|7902379xxx|01.09.2017|25|||239|Stores Sheffield|||07.01.2018|13.10.2016||X||NP
                       ^
                       |
                  This is 24th char position
```

**since you have not posted without codetags, I assume, its one line, which contains total 27 fields, where separator being pipe (`|`)**

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$24="filename.txt"}1' file
```

If you want to have current filename at 24th field then, use `FILENAME`

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$24=FILENAME}1' file
```

- And you have tried, `NF-2` which gives 25, you still can correct your
  code with `NF-3` so that it will modify 24th field

> To insert some string at char position 24, I prefer `sed`

```
sed -r -e 's/^.{24}/&filename.txt/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\| '{ for (i=1;i<=NF-2;i++) { printf "%s|",$i };printf "%s","filename";for (i=NF-1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "|%s",$x } }' filename
```

Print the all the | delimited fields up to X and print using a for loop. Print "filename" and then print the remaining fields.